# How To Get Task Lists from Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get a list of Task Lists using Microsoft Graph. My code to do this is:

```
$response = $graph->createRequest('GET','/me/todo/lists')
                ->execute();
```

I see the data I need if I print_r($response) but I don't know how to get to it. I need the name and ID of each task list.

Here's the output from print_r (with sensitive data removed):

```
    Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse Object
(
    [_body:Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
        (
            [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #7
            [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
            [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
            [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
            [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
            [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
            [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [_decodedBody:Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse:private] => Array
        (
            [@odata.context] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('d703696f-8857-4e3a-9450-1dca274f88eb')/todo/lists
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [@odata.etag] => W/"a8YdGeniGU+vgVPY5PzR3gAFCYZf7A=="
                            [displayName] => Tasks
                            [isOwner] => 1
                            [isShared] => 
                            [wellknownListName] => defaultList
                            [id] => <list id>
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [@odata.etag] => W/"a8YdGeniGU+vgVPY5PzR3gAFCYa4SQ=="
                            [displayName] => Test List
                            [isOwner] => 1
                            [isShared] => 
                            [wellknownListName] => none
                            [id] => <list id>
                        )

                )

        )

    [_headers:Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse:private] => Array
        (
            [Date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Wed, 02 Jun 2021 21:16:11 GMT
                )

            [Content-Type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
                )

            [Cache-Control] => Array
                (
                    [0] => no-cache
                )

            [Transfer-Encoding] => Array
                (
                    [0] => chunked
                )

            [Strict-Transport-Security] => Array
                (
                    [0] => max-age=31536000
                )

            [request-id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5e73fcae-571d-4a3d-8cd0-88a469c2d8d6
                )

            [client-request-id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5e73fcae-571d-4a3d-8cd0-88a469c2d8d6
                )

            [x-ms-ags-diagnostic] => Array
                (
                    [0] => {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"SN1PEPF0000649D"}}
                )

            [OData-Version] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4.0
                )

        )

    [_httpStatusCode:Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphResponse:private] => 200
    [_request] => Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphRequest Object
        (
            [accessToken:protected] => <access token>
            [apiVersion:protected] => v1.0
            [baseUrl:protected] => https://graph.microsoft.com/
            [endpoint:protected] => /me/todo/lists
            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [Host] => https://graph.microsoft.com/
                    [Content-Type] => application/json
                    [SdkVersion] => Graph-php-1.9.0
                    [Authorization] => <auth token>
                )

            [requestBody:protected] => 
            [requestType:protected] => GET
            [returnsStream:protected] => 
            [returnType:protected] => 
            [timeout:protected] => 0
            [proxyPort:protected] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: What does the print_r output look like then? And which bit do you want specifically?

Comment: I edited my question to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The properties containing the data all seem to be private or protected. Probably the class offers some functions by which you can get access to it. Check the documentation and/or source code

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I keep getting "class not found" errors for the Todo class. I posted a separate question for that problem.